# Linux system throws an error on a .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net, linux, windows, .net-core

I wrote a console application in .NET Core for linux. When I try to run it on my linux vps it throws that error:

```
Could not resolve type with token 01000010
  at Lumo.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00039] in <dff92c70c42444648f6bf1be28aa709c>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000010
  at Lumo.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00039] in <dff92c70c42444648f6bf1be28aa709c>:0
```

here's my main C# code:

```
string city;
 Console.WriteLine("lolyweather");
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
   Console.Write("Enter your city: ");
   city = Console.ReadLine();
   string link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&appid=" + API_KEY + "&units=metric&cnt=6";
 GetWeather(link, city);
```

and here's the GetWeather function:

```
 public static void GetWeather(string url, string city)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = response as HttpWebResponse;
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WD.RootObject>(json);
                        WD.RootObject weather = obj;


                        Console.WriteLine("There are " + weather.weather[0].main.ToString() + " in {0}", city);
                        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} \u00B0C.", Math.Round(weather.main.temp));
                        Console.WriteLine("Max temperature: {0}, Minimum temperature: {1}", Math.Round(weather.main.temp_max), Math.Round(weather.main.temp_min));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Program crashed: {ex.Message} (Check if you wrote your city's name correctly!)");
                Thread.Sleep(1_000);
            }
        }
```

anyone knows what is up?

Comment: Delete your **`bin`** *and* **`obj`** folders, rebuild. Does this work?

Comment: I just tried it. Sadly it doesn't

Comment: In the csproj file what is the <TargetFramework> ?

Comment: @James ```<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>``` it's this one

Comment: What kind of Linux VPS? Please be more specific. And also what's the command you used to run the app.

Comment: @LexLi it's Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (64bit). I just installed dotnet on my vps and then uploaded the dll file and ran it by ./appname

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment it sounds like you built a framework dependent version of your .NET core app.  You cannot just upload the dll and have it execute without installing the .NET Runtime or creating a self contained deployment. I would recommend that you either install the .NET Runtime on your VPS, which includes you copying all of the output from your dotnet publish command or creating a self-contained deployment as part of your publish step an upload that.

Try this command and copy the output in the publish folder and let us know if it works.

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained true
```

Differences between framework dependent and self-contained can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying